# rewrites in next js working fine in local, but not working after deployment in vercel

Tags: next.js, frontend, nextjs-rewrites

```
this is how my next.config.js looks like => 
{
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: `/:path*`,
      },
        {
          source: '/sell',
          destination: `${NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/sell`,
        },
        {
          source: '/sell/:path*',
          destination: `${NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL}/sell/:path*`,
        },
      ]
  }
}
```

for /sell => i am using another website [www.anotherWebsite.com/sell](http://www.anotherWebsite.com/sell) to show.
it is working perfectly in local, but not working after deployment in vercel.

for /sell => it should show website [www.anotherWebsite.com/sell](http://www.anotherWebsite.com/sell).
as it is working in my local.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vercel's hosting, but do they allow redirection to external sites? They may block these by default and require a whitelist.

Comment: this is nextjs documents to rewrite to an external URL 
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Comment: I am facing the same issue.